# Cognitive Service Face api use local image - PHP

Tags: php, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to upload an local image to the face API by using PHP, I use the sample code to call the api and it is fine when i am using JSON. but it get stuck when change to octet-stream. i use the below code by referencing "https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php"

```
$image = "images/face-021.jpg";
$fp = fopen($image, 'r+');
$request->addUpload('stuff', $fp, 'custom.name', 'application/octet-stream');
```

and i  get the below responds form the api.

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => InvalidImageSize
        [message] => Image size is too small or too big.
    )
)
```

Am i missing some step before passing the binary data to the api?

The image size is just 956 KB and the dimensions is 2448 x 2448

Comment: your image is too small or too big

Comment: This is not PHP related. Try resizing the image first: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.imagick.php

Comment: Usually it's a good practice to read error messages that you receive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Face API does not support multipart MIME payloads.  You should instead send the image directly in the body of the request.

```
$image = 'images/face-021.jpg';
$fp = fopen($image, 'rb');
$request->setBody($fp);
$request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
```

Comment: It works now. really appreciate your help =)
I don't know the API does not support multipart MIME payloads(maybe i miss something on document) and I though i have to follow the function on "pear" upload the file byusing `addUpload()`. so i stuck on the upload part.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
function microimg() { 
    //$GLOBALS['telegram']->ssendmessage($GLOBALS['userid'], $urlImage);      
    $request = new Http_Request2('https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect');
    $url1 = $request->getUrl();

    $headers = array(`enter code here`
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    );

    $request->setHeader($headers);

    $parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
    'returnFaceId' => 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks' => 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes' => 'age',
    );

    $parameters = array();
    $url1->setQueryVariables($parameters);
    $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

    //$request->setBody('{"url":  "http://miladddddddddddddd.ml/fillter_image/photos/file_93.jpg" }');
    $request->setBody('{"url":  "'.$GLOBALS['fileurl'].'" }');
    $err = $request->setBody;
    try {
        $response = $request->send();
        echo $response->getBody();
        $ed = $response->getBody();
        $GLOBALS['telegram']->ssendmessage($GLOBALS['userid'],$ed);
         $GLOBALS['telegram']->ssendmessage($GLOBALS['userid'], $GLOBALS['fileurl']);      
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        echo $ex;
    }
}


microimg($urlimg);
```

Comment: An explanation for this answer would be useful.